# Any way in coan to have it not evaluate certain parts of my code base?

Tags: preprocessor-directive

Hitting "**##-operator does not compose a token in definition**" using **coan** with a macro definition like this:

```
#define MY_STRINGIFY_CONCAT_MACRO(_x) \
   a = #_x; \
   b = #_x; \
   c = prefix_ ## _x;
```

... which, from my compiler's perspective, is perfectly valid.

Having this code in x.c, then

```
$ coan source -gw x.c
coan: /home/andreasl/c/onion/no_ear/x.c: line 4: error 0x0081b: ##-operator does not compose a token in definition >>a = #_x; b = #_x; c = prefix_ ## _x;<< of "MY_STRINGIFY_CONCAT_MACRO(_x)"
```

(For those interested in debugging this: it doesn't occur if you omit either first or second stringification.)

Not expecting to get this fixed anytime soon, I'd like to know if there's some (undocumented) way to mark given section of my code for being 'ignored' (so passed through 'as is') by coan, e.g. some special

```
#ifndef COAN_PLEASE_ACCEPT_AND_LEAVE_AS_IS
  ...
#endif
```

... I could enclose such code with?

Or any other idea how to deal with this elegantly?
(I'm currently working this around by writing extra code allowing me to omit one of the two stringifications.)

```
> coan --version
coan, version 6.0.1 for 64 bit Unix/Linux(built Sep 15 2014,18:42:46)
```